# Increasing the speed of `lme` in the package `nlme`, or, equivalent code in `lme4`

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I want to evaluate a dataset with linear mixed effects. Usually I am a Mathematica user, which doesn't have support for this, so I am using `R` within Mathematica using [RLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/guide/RLink.html). I've managed to get good results using `nlme` with the `lme` function:

```
MyDataFrame=data.frame(x=x, PopulationLabel=factor(PopulationLabel));
library(nlme);
results = lme(
                x~1, data=MyDataFrame, random=~1|PopulationLabel, weights=varIdent(form = ~1|PopulationLabel), 
                method = 'REML', control = lmeControl(opt = 'optim', maxIter = 1000, msMaxIter = 1000)
            );
summary(results)$tTable
```

Here `y` is the data point and `pop` is the grouping label. The issue I am running into is when I have 200 groupings or more (in a dataset with roughly 3500 data points in total) is computation time, here is a plot with computation time as a function of the number of groupings:

[image]

Now I realise with a large number of groupings I should expect to pay for this in computation time, but I have a large number of these sets to evaluate -- so I would like to optimise if possible. But I understand that the only course of action may be to run the code overnight or over a weekend, or to parallelise as much as possible.

I have read that `nlme` is an older package and that `lme4` may be better optimised, however I am not an experience `R` user so I am struggling with the syntax. Can anyone show me how to write the equivalent of the code above in `lme4`, or, if anyone knows any other packages that may do what I want faster -- I would be very grateful!

---

### Further information

I had a question in the comments about the nature of my problem. I am looking at time series data which are normally distributed, but the mean and variance may change at random points, for example:

[image]

This is a simulated dataset, so I know where the changes occur, in this particular example the changes in local population means is very small so a weighted mean is probably enough, but I want to compare a weighted mean approach to a linear mixed effects approach -- hence my use of `lme` from `nlme`. I am using change-point analysis on real data to group the data.

Here is a data sample which has been grouped using a change-point analysis:
https://pastebin.com/B8uyt7sj

With my current `nlme` code this would take between 6-10 minutes to evaluate.

Comment: You seem to be using one of the non-standard optimisers, why?

Comment: I suspect your performance issue results from fitting group-wise weights. Is it really necessary to fit them? Could you perhaps supply starting values for the weights? Or could you use a different variance structure such as a variance function of some variance co-variate?

Comment: @Roland Its interesting that you say this because I thought that might help, and if this were mathematica, I would know how to do this! But I wasn't sure how to in R. Would you be willing to provide an example?

Comment: @usεr11852 If I am honest, ignorance. I managed to cobble this together from different sources -- what optimiser would you recomend?

Comment: What is/was wrong with the default `nlminb`? And yes, `lmer` can be faster.  And Roland is right `weights` probably kills this speed-wise.

Comment: I'll change the optimiser and compare results and computation time. I figured weights are necessary as my populations won't necessarily have the same variance, or sample size -- hence I wanted to weight with inverse variance found using REML methods.

Comment: What is the purpose of your model (your research question(s))?

Comment: @RobertLong I think a question modification may be in order, what's the best way to add a sample of data?

Comment: If it's a small extract then just use `dput(mydata)` and add the result of that to your post using the Edit option and enclusing it with 3 backticks (```) before and after. If it's too much to post like that then just put it somewhere it is accessible (eg github) and just post the link to it in your question, along with perhaps a `summary(mydata)` and `str(mydata)`

Comment: @RobertLong Thanks, I amended my question.

Comment: OK great :) But I still don't know what your research question is ? What is the purpose of this modelling ? Do you want to do prediction or inference. If inference then what are you interested in knowing ?

Comment: I'm recording data as a time series, where I expect the fluctuation in the mean to be small (but not necessarily non-existent). However there may be physical phenomena which increase the variance -- for example a voltage measurement may have increased scatter when temperatures increase -- I am interested in an estimate for a mean of the entire dataset. If the fluctuation in the mean were non-existent I would go for a fixed effect model in the form of a weighted mean, constructed from means and SE of sub-populations, which are in turn found with change-point analysis.

Comment: OK. How much fluctuation in mean do you expect ? Also, by how much do you expect the variance to vary by group ?

Comment: Tricky to answer. I might expect stability for a certain about of time, but it as for variance it really depends on conditions. I would not expect to see fluctuations greater than 3 or 4 times the smallest variance size -- the example plot is pretty representative. As for the mean, the fluctuation is small compared to the fluctuation in the variance. But again, this is what I want to find out, hence I compare a fixed effect to a linear mixed effect evaluation strategy.. I've created a chat for us in case you need further info: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127991/chat-for-536296

Comment: (With reproducible code) this is a better fit on SO